Can Husserl's impressions be mereologically expressible?
In Husserl's phenomenology, hyletic data (hylé, "matter") are the raw sensory impressions—such as colors, sounds, or textures—provided by "impressions" before being shaped by intentional consciousness. These data are passive, non-intentional, and form the given material basis for meaningful experiences. Although present in every object, they are only accessible by an exercise of abstraction which, according to Husserl, can alter their content (as if analysis were a thermometer that alters the temperature of the water it purports to measure "neutrally").
Hyletic data are contrasted with morphé (form), the structuring activity of consciousness that organizes these impressions into coherent objects. For example, the sensory impressions of a rose’s color and shape are hyletic, while the intentional act of perceiving it as a "rose" (= noema) involves the structuring work (= noesis) of consciousness.
Since they are preconceptual, we have the classic problem of how to conceptualise the non-conceptual (Hegel, Sellars et al). Husserl himself speaks of them as literally a ‘component’ of the whole which is the object, so it is clear that he is using the mereology of the III Investigation to categorise them. The question is whether it does so from within themselves, or whether it does so by looking at them from the whole (noema) that makes them up.
So the question is whether they really, being preconceptual, can be analysed in terms of wholes and parts, being mereology a conceptual tool (I guess). I think the best way to understand them is as simple objects, because if I say that they are ‘part-of’ a whole, I am already presupposing the whole (noema) to access the parts, and therefore putting conceptual elements into them.

Indeed the mere act of identifying parts of hyletic data as moments of experience, which is posited by Husserl to be inseparable from the flow of consciousness, might itself already involve a kind of theory-laden real noesistic structuring from the assembling ideality whole noema singly pointed by intentionality, which was already emphasized and cautioned in Yogacara schools since ancient described in some obscure legendary Abhidharma such as One Hundred Wonderful Doors Dharma. Btw, as mereoology cannot form singleton compared to membership, thus such noema can't form ordered relations...

@DoubleKnot Well, I really had to reread your comment three times to understand it. If you can express yourself in a way that the rest of us, common mortals, can understand you, I would appreciate it. Yes, there are many similarities with this problem in Buddhist philosophy, not only Yogachara, but also Madhyamaka and the question of whether there are irreducible elements or dhatus, but better not to complicate the matter. What do you mean by ‘as mereoology cannot form singleton compared to membership, thus such noema cannot form ordered relations...’?

@DoubleKnot If you are referring to whether the whole of intentional correlation (noema-noesis) lacks mediate and immediate parts, let me remind you, as you surely already know, that it does indeed have them according to the III UI: not all parts or moments have the same immediacy within a whole. For example: brilliance inheres in color, color in a surface, surface is a
moment of extension, and extension is a moment of a solid object, which finally can be taken as an independent thing. In such a case brilliance would be mediately a moment of surface, but immediately a moment of color.

My btw is a critique of mereology's limited expressiveness compared to set theory, since without membership only parthood, such noetic structuring work cannot even express ordered pairs/relations, you need something else subtly to form Kantian time sequence. As for your hierarchical noematic intentionalities (Leibniz warned brilliance and color as secondary properties are not hyletic long ago), I don't see any conflict here once you have the above mentioned subtle sequential structure from that something else which the Abhidharmas further developed...

@DoubleKnot The truth is that, putting aside the problem of mathematical foundation, I don't see anything phenomenologically relevant that cannot be addressed with the mereology of the Third Investigation. So unless you give me some example I'm really not follwing you, sorry

@DoubleKnot Can't you talk about an ordered pair using "moments" or non-independent parts? Color and extension are two inseparable parts or moments; there is no one without the other. There you have a way to explain relationships. If you need to order them, you can appeal to the mediate and immediate parts. And again, this is mathematical problem, not a phenomenological one.
